# How to allow downloading files from S3 only to AWS Cognito users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

In my AWS project, I use Cognito to allow both authenticated and unauthenticated users to use my Android app. I also use S3 to store files that the users can download from the app.

Here is the content of my S3 bucket:

```
myS3Bucket:
   - folderAll
   - folderUserGroup
```

In that bucket, `folderAll` contains files that can be downloaded by each user of my app, and `folderUserGroup` contains files that can only be downloaded by authenticated users that are in a specific Cognito user group.

Neither the files of `folderAll` nor the files of `folderUserGroup` should be allowed to be downloaded outside of the app, for example using a web browser.

I already configured a Cognito user pool and identity pool, with roles for both authenticated and unauthenticated users like, for example, the authenticated user role:

```
  MyIdentityPoolRoleAuthenticated:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my-identity-pool-authenticated
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              Federated: 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud':
                  Ref: MyIdentityPool
              'ForAnyValue:StringLike':
                'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': authenticated
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'MyIdentityPoolRoleAuthenticatedPolicy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Action:
                  - 'mobileanalytics:PutEvents'
                  - 'cognito-sync:*'
                  - 'cognito-identity:*'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::myS3Bucket/*"
```

So I tried to follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html) or [this](https://medium.com/@haydnjmorris/uploading-photos-to-aws-s3-getting-started-with-cognito-and-iam-c96ba5b5496d), but I don't understand how to configure the S3 and Cognito roles and policies to achieve my need.

How can I configure my roles and policies to restrict files download only to my Cognito users?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how much have you done so far?

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan I already setup a complete environment with a fully working Cognito user pool and identity pool, and a S3 bucket. The only thing I don't understand is how to setup the IAM roles and policies to achieve my need.

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan I just updated my question, but I still have a 403 error.

Comment: You haven't posted your code. You have only posted the policies. Where is the code that's trying to access the files

Answer (score 0):

I cant quite remember how you do it with S3 policies/IAM directly, but I like to route all my authenticated traffic through AWS API Gateway as it has nice integration with Cognito.

You can then setup an S3 proxy (loads of google resources on this) through API Gateway and tell API Gateway to only allow authenticated users to see s3 content. You use an ‘authorizor’ in api gateway to do this. No code needed. Integrates directly with cognito.

I always feel like this is the best practice way of giving users access to restricted content. I think there are ways to give actual IAM roles through Congnito, but this always makes me feel uncomfortable. The usecase of Cognito for me, is keeping your 'users' all in one place. I like giving API Gateway the responsibility of integrating with Cognito and controlling access to restricted areas - feels like the most obvious way to do it to me.

The solution is too involved to provide a full solution here. AWS has the following resource on [Expose API Methods to Access an Amazon S3 Object in a Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-items-in-folder-as-s3-objects-in-bucket) and also how to [Control Access to a REST API Using Amazon Cognito User Pools as Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)

Comment: Thanks, but my goal here is to download file, not calling webservices (I already use API Gateway for that purpose, though)...

Comment: if you already use api gateway, adding another resource to act as an s3 proxy, with cognito authentication is SUPER easy. Make life easier for yourself, use what you have.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that later. I actually didn't know I could use S3 through API Gateway.

Comment: No probs. Just google s3 proxy with api gateway. You then need to setup and api gateway authorizor to integrate with cognito. It will then do all the auth for you. No code needed!

Comment: @matteoh see updated answer with links to aws guides, shout if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow only your AWS Cognito pool users access your bucket you can create a policy like below. You just need to replace your own **bucket-name** and **application-name**:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ListYourObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": ["cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ReadWriteDeleteYourObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Reference

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Comment: What is the `application-name`? I cannot remember using the term `application name` or using it when creating my aws application. I have a company name, api name and a bunch of other things my application is identified by. Where do you find that?

Comment: application-name here refers to cognito's user pool app client. You can find it here: 
cognito -> manage cognito pools -> your cognito pool -> App clients

Comment: What do you do with this policy ?  Attach to the bucket, the Cognito user, the Cognito Group or the Cognito user pool ?